# Rails ActiveRecord: How do I know if find_or_create_by found or created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I do

```
widget = Widget.find_or_create_by_widgetid(:widgetid => "12345", :param2 => "folk")
```

etc. then how do I tell if newobj is a found or newly created Widget? Is there something I can test conditionally on `widget` that will tell me?

Comment: You could check the `created_at` attribute and compare it to `Time.now` to get some sort of idea too.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to tell if the object is newly created or was already there. You could use `find_or_initialize_by_widgetid` instead which doesn't save the new object. You can then check `widget.new_record?` which will tell you whether the object has been saved or not. You'd have to put a save call in the block of code for a new object but as you want to make that check anyway it shouldn't ruin the flow of the code.

So:

```
widget = find_or_initialize_by_widgetid(:widgetid => "12345", :param2 => "folk")
if widget.new_record?
  widget.save!
  # Code for a new widget
else
  # Code for an existing widget
end
```

Comment: I started looking at doing it this way, thanks for confirming it as a viable option.

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, you might also use `find_or_initialize_by_widgetid` with a block. The block will only be executed for the newly initialized record.

Comment: `find_or_create_by_` also accepts a block which will be passed to `create` and thus only run if a new record is created.

Answer (score 36):

## Rails 4+

#### [find_or_create_by(attributes, &block)](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by)

Now this method accepts a block, which is passed down to create, so I'd go with:

```
widget = Widget.find_or_create_by(:widgetid => "12345", :param2 => "folk") do |w|
  # if you got in here, this is a new widget
end
```

Another way to do this in Rails 4+ would be:

```
widget = Widget.where(:widgetid => "12345", :param2 => "folk").first_or_initialize

if widget.new_record?
  # this is a new widget
end
```

Answer (score -3):

Depending of what you want to do, you might use a block:

```
widget = find_or_create_by(widgetid: "12345") do |widget|
  widget.param2 = "folk"
  if widget.new_record?
    # Code for a new widget.
  else
    # Code for an existing widget.
  end
end
```

Comment: Actually, as artm states above (and the documentation states), the block is only passed to 'create' so there is no need to check for new.